# Git: How do I view file contents before a specific commit

Tags: git

I'm using

**git show *commithash*:*filename***

to get the version of the file right before the change.

How could I get the version right before that change was made, for comparation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question, you can go back as far as you want in your commit log to see whatever changes you want. And you can do it using the same command you're already using, but just change the commit hash to whichever commit you want to see.

Using this commit log as an example:

```
 commit 123456789baf76cbbb9a2e7052f4aeb987654321
 Author: Ron Swanson <ron@swanson.com>
 Date:   Wed Nov 11 12:02:57 2015 -0500

     Fix Expired listings ordering for when deactivated early

 commit 9876543217a52dfd4387c6eb6f31431123456789
 Author: Leslie Knope <leslie@knope.com>
 Date:   Tue Nov 10 14:18:30 2015 -0500

     Only sync user if relevant attributes have changed
```

You can use `git show 123456789baf76cbbb9a2e7052f4aeb987654321` to show all changes for the `Fix Expired listings ordering for when deactivated early` commit.

Or you can use `git show 9876543217a52dfd4387c6eb6f31431123456789` to show all changes for the `Only sync user if relevant attributes have changed` commit.

Comment: Not exactly, I need to do this from a script, so I was wondering if there is a way to obtain the entire file before and after let's say Ron's changes, knowing only his SHA1.

Love the Parks reference, btw